# how to use regular expression in javascript to extract value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regular expression in javascript to extract values. The string is in this pattern "title{position}", how should i get title and position in this example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's all there is too it (no nesting of '{}'s or anything) `(\w+)\{(\w+)\}` will match that instance and group the results as groups 1 and 2. Do you need anything more complicated like a collection of many of these per string or is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Is that string everything? If so there's no need for matching. Just split the string!

```
var str = "foo{bar}";
var pieces = str.split(/\{|\}/);

var title = pieces[0];
var position = pieces[1];

alert("Title: " + title + "\nPosition: " + position);
```

[Demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/xAVkF/)

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to add results to a structure -

```
var arr = [];

var text = 'title{position}';
text.replace(/(\w+){(\w+)}/g, function(m, key, value){
    //alert('title is-'+key);
    //alert('position is-'+value);
    arr.push({"title":key,"position":value});
});
console.log(arr);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Sr6Ed/1/